# SwiftUI: Justify Text

Tags: swiftui, text-alignment

In UIKit there is the option to justify text so that it looks like in a newspaper. However I can not find this option in SwiftUI on Textelement. I only found multiline alignment with .trailing, .leading, .center.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Use UILabel with UIViewRepresentable

Answer (score 13, accepted):

SwiftUI doesn't yet support justified text, so you'll have to wrap a UIKit view with [UIViewRepresentable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uiviewrepresentable). So, for justified text, you could wrap [UITextView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextview). It would look something like this:

```swift
struct TextView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var text: String
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFont.TextStyle.body)
        textView.textAlignment = .justified
        return textView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
        uiView.text = text
    }
}
```

And from here, you can use it in your views like this:

```
struct MyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TextView(text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin quis elementum lorem. Nullam fermentum viverra ipsum a finibus. Vestibulum venenatis risus vel leo sagittis, id aliquet tortor elementum. Aenean elementum orci ac sapien dictum laoreet. Sed placerat, magna sit amet eleifend auctor, odio ligula dapibus lacus, quis interdum ligula velit at est. Curabitur molestie dui sodales faucibus cursus. Duis posuere ex diam, tempor tincidunt nunc venenatis vitae. Integer vulputate odio vitae enim tincidunt, eget vulputate arcu pulvinar. Integer in magna erat.")
        .frame(width: 500, height: 300)
    }
}
```